# opening balance and closing balance in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

How to get opening balance for given period of time my format is-->

`opening balance -- debit--credit--closing balance;`

and my

opening balance formula:

```
if({Command.dt}<={?fromdate}) 
then {Command.debit} --
```

and

transactions formula:

```
if({Command.dt}>={?fromdate}) and ({Command.dt}<={?todate}) 
then ({Command.debit}) --
```

and

closing balance formula:

```
({@opening_balance}+{@transaction_balance}-{Command.credit}).
```

If I give the date from 01.01.2010 to 31.12.2010 that is from beginning of my records , opening balance value shows correctly, but if i give the date for particular period from 01.02.2010 or 01.0.2010 to 31.12.2010 my opening balance result will be wrong.

Please help me.

Comment: Solve this issue, please help me

Comment: Sir, Please anybody help and save my job

Comment: what do you mean by `correctly` and `wrongly`.. can you explain more clearly... Also not only `Crystal Reports 2008` tag `Crystal Reports` as well, As it reaches more people.. Now I am tagging for you.

Comment: Wrong operator in opening balance formula - you need not "<=", but "<".

Comment: On 01.01.2010 transaction - Opening balance  = 1400, Debit balance = 2800,  credit balance = 800,  closing balance=(1400+2800-800) 3400

on 02.01.2010 transaction- Opening balance  = 3400, Debit balance = 300,  credit balance = 400, closing balance=(3400+300-400) 3300

on 03.01.2010 transaction - Opening balance  = 3300, Debit balance = 450, credit balance = 600, closing balance=(3300+450-600) 3150

on 04.01.2010 transaction- Opening balance  =3150, Debit balance = 175, credit balance = 350, closing balance=(3150+175-350) 2975

Comment: If I give the date from 01.01.2010 to 03.01.2010 that is from beginning of my records, opening balance value shows 1400, but if i give the date from 02.01.2010 to 04.01.2010 or 03.01.2010 to 04.01.2010 opening balance is 0 but I need 3400 or 3300 as opening balance for the above said date period respectively. Please help me